# terraform resource aws_ssm_association is throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I have successfully applied the following terraform code.

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "webssmassoc" {
name = "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:*********:document/a4s-bl-automation"
association_name = "${var.service_name}-dt-webserver-association"
parameters = {
  AssumeRole = aws_iam_role.dt_automation_role.arn
  InstanceId = data.aws_instance.webinstance.id
}
apply_only_at_cron_interval = true
schedule_expression = "cron(0 14 ? * ${local.dayOfWeek} *)"
}
```

I now make a small change in the schedule expression and run a terraform plan, terraform detects the change properly.

```
  # aws_ssm_association.webssmassoc will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_ssm_association" "webssmassoc" {
        id                          = "0b9ee1a4-6011-4a9c-9055-2cca172b061e"
        name                        = "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:497882509041:document/a4s-oneagent-reboot-automation"
      ~ schedule_expression         = "cron(0 14 ? * TUE *)" -> "cron(0 15 ? * TUE *)"
        # (6 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

When I run terraform apply, it errors out.

```
│ Error: Error updating SSM association: ValidationException: Must specify both Automation Target Parameter Name and Targets   
│       status code: 400, request id: e4e80ff6-1235-4355-9221-2031a1fb922d
│
│   with aws_ssm_association.webssmassoc,
│   on main.tf line 118, in resource "aws_ssm_association" "webssmassoc":
│  118: resource "aws_ssm_association" "webssmassoc" {
```

Extra information:
The document being associated is an automation document.
provider being used is hashicorp/aws v4.33.0
terraform v1.1.5

Is this a terraform bug? Or is it working the way it is intended to?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use targets block as explained in the TF docs?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for your swift reply. I did try that. It errored out as well.   

Error: Error creating SSM association: ValidationException: Must specify both Automation Target Parameter Name and Targets   
       status code: 400, request id: 

Then I added the 

_automation_target_parameter_name="InstanceId"_

to get rid of the error and again it errored out.

Error: Error creating SSM association: InvalidTarget: Cannot pass Instance Ids into an automation association
```

Comment: @Marcin, even when I configure the same via the aws portal, I choose _simple execution_ 
 and so I don't even see the fields for specifying targets.  I leave them empty. I only pass my parameters. Those fields become visible only when I choose 'rate control' Execution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with an AWS-owned Automation document type. The following worked for me:

1. Add `automation_target_parameter_name = "InstanceId"`.
2. Add `targets` with the `tag:Tag Name` key. The `InstanceIds` key will return an `InvalidTarget: Cannot pass Instance Ids into an automation association` error.

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "example" {
  name                             = data.aws_ssm_document.some_doc.arn
  
  automation_target_parameter_name = "InstanceId"
  
  parameters                       = {
    InstanceId           = data.aws_instance.some_instance.id
    AutomationAssumeRole = aws_iam_role.ssm_automation_role.arn
  }
  
  targets {
    key    = "tag:Tag Name"
    values = ["my-ec2-tag"]
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I don't have a tag to use for the association, and I only want to use the InstanceId to find the appropriate resource? (In my case, I'm using the association to stop an RDS instance) Removing the "targets" block throws an error, having the "targets" block with an InstanceIds key will throw as well as you mentioned

Comment: figured it out, the right values for "empty" targets are targets {
    key    = "aws:NoOpAutomationTag"
    values = ["AWS-NoOpAutomationTarget-Value"]
  }